# Import & modify date data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, import-from-csv

I have a .csv file with records written in the following form:

```
2010-04-20 15:15:00,"8.9915176259e+00","8.8562623697e+00"
2010-04-20 15:30:00,"8.5718021723e+00","8.6633827160e+00"
2010-04-20 15:45:00,"8.4484844117e+00","8.4336586330e+00"
2010-04-20 16:00:00,"1.1106980342e+01","8.4333062208e+00"
2010-04-20 16:15:00,"9.0643470589e+00","8.6885660103e+00"
2010-04-20 16:30:00,"8.2133517943e+00","8.2677822671e+00"
2010-04-20 16:45:00,"8.2499419380e+00","8.1523501983e+00"
2010-04-20 17:00:00,"8.2948492278e+00","8.2884797924e+00"
```

From these data I would like to make clusters - I would like to add a column with number indicating the hour - so in case of the first row a value 15 has to be added in a new row.

The first problem is that calling a function

```
[numData, textData, rawData] = xlsread('testData.csv')
```

creates an empty matrix numData and one-column textData and rawData structures.

Is it possible to create any template which recognizes a yyyy, MM, dd, hh, mm, ss values from the data above?

What I would basically like to do with these data is to categorize the values by hours so from the example row of input:

```
2010-04-20 15:15:00,"8.9915176259e+00","8.8562623697e+00"
```

**update 1:
in Matlab the line above is recognized as a string:**

> '2010-04-26 13:00:00,"1.0428104753e+00","2.3456394130e+00"'

I would want this to be the output:

```
15, 8.9915176259e+00, 8.8562623697e+00
```

**update 1:
a string has to be parsed**

Does anyone know how to parse a string and retrieve a timestamp ('2010-04-20 15:15:00'), value1 (1.0428104753e+00) and value2 (2.3456394130e+00) from it as separate values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use [XLSREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html) with your sample file data, I get the correct outputs just as [yuk did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874359/import-modify-date-data-in-matlab/2874585#2874585). This statement from the documentation for [XLSREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html) may explain the problem you are getting:

> If your system does not have Excel for
>   Windows installed, or MATLAB cannot
>   access the COM server, `xlsread`
>   operates in basic mode. In this mode,
>   `xlsread` only reads XLS files.

As an alternative, I was also able to read your sample data file using [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html):

```
>> fid = fopen('testData.csv','r');                    %# Open the file
>> data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s','Delimiter',',',...  %# Read the data
                   'CollectOutput',true);
>> fclose(fid);                                        %# Close the file
>> data = strrep(data{1},'"','')  %# Format the data and remove '"'

data = 

    '2010-04-20 15:15:00'    '8.9915176259e+00'    '8.8562623697e+00'
    '2010-04-20 15:30:00'    '8.5718021723e+00'    '8.6633827160e+00'
    '2010-04-20 15:45:00'    '8.4484844117e+00'    '8.4336586330e+00'
    '2010-04-20 16:00:00'    '1.1106980342e+01'    '8.4333062208e+00'
    '2010-04-20 16:15:00'    '9.0643470589e+00'    '8.6885660103e+00'
    '2010-04-20 16:30:00'    '8.2133517943e+00'    '8.2677822671e+00'
    '2010-04-20 16:45:00'    '8.2499419380e+00'    '8.1523501983e+00'
    '2010-04-20 17:00:00'    '8.2948492278e+00'    '8.2884797924e+00'
```

Now you can format the strings in the cell array `data` into a matrix of numeric values using [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html), [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html), and [STR2NUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/str2num.html):

```
>> dateVectors = datevec(data(:,1));  %# Format the date string
>> newData = [dateVectors(:,4) cellfun(@str2num,(data(:,2:3)))]

newData =                        %# A numeric matrix

   15.0000    8.9915    8.8563
   15.0000    8.5718    8.6634
   15.0000    8.4485    8.4337
   16.0000   11.1070    8.4333
   16.0000    9.0643    8.6886
   16.0000    8.2134    8.2678
   16.0000    8.2499    8.1524
   17.0000    8.2948    8.2885
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datevec('2010-04-20 15:15:00')
ans =

        2010           4          20          15          15           0
```

str2num for the other two columns and csvwrite will also be your friend.

I am not sure I understand all of your question, but I suspect this will get you well on the way to solving it.

Comment: Sorry, Doug, haven't seen your answer.

Comment: You can always delete your answer before you get the reputation points that I want! :)

Comment: Thanks Doug for a response regarding the timestamp parsing. I've refined a question about the string parsing so hopefully now is clearer what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html) to convert date strings to year, month, day, hours, minutes and sec.

```
DV = datevec(textData)

DV =

        2010           4          20          15          15           0
        2010           4          20          15          30           0
        2010           4          20          15          45           0
        2010           4          20          16           0           0
        2010           4          20          16          15           0
        2010           4          20          16          30           0
        2010           4          20          16          45           0
        2010           4          20          17           0           0

Hours = DV(:,4);
```

**EDIT**:

If I use (R2010a) your sample data and your code

```
[numData, textData, rawData] = xlsread('testData.csv')
```

I get two last columns in numData and the first column in textData. Applying DATEVEC to textData will convert the date string to numbers.

**EDIT2**:

To parse your string you can do, for example:

```
s = '2010-04-20 15:15:00,"8.9915176259","8.8562623697"';
s2 = regexprep(s,'"','');
A = textscan(s2,'%s %f %f','Delimiter',',');
DV = datevec(A{1});
result = [DV(4) A{2:3}];
```

Comment: I tried to use xlsread but again numData is empty while rawData and textData are 2857x1 structures (there are 2857 records in the file).

Comment: s2 = '2010-04-20 15:15:00,8.9915176259e+00,8.8562623697e+00'

>> A = textscan(s2,'%s %f %f','Delimiter',',');
??? Error using ==> textscan
First input must be of type double or string.

Comment: Because you are applying textscan to cell array of strings. I would use textscan to read the file, if xlsread does not work as expected, but you already get that answer from gnovice.

Answer (score 0):

using
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19707-xls2struct

and assuming your .csv file has a 'header' row. I used (time, v1, v2) for this example:

```
 data=xls2struct('t.csv');
 timeVec = datevec(data.time);
 data.time = timeVec(:,4); %replace time with hours
 matData=[data.time, data.v1,data.v2] %concat data from the struct

matData =

   15.0000    8.9915    8.8563
   15.0000    8.5718    8.6634
   15.0000    8.4485    8.4337
   16.0000   11.1070    8.4333
   16.0000    9.0643    8.6886
   16.0000    8.2134    8.2678
   16.0000    8.2499    8.1524
   17.0000    8.2948    8.2885
```